# Does Alita have a third body?

Tags: alita-battle-angel

In the very last scene of *Alita: Battle Angel*, does Alita have a third body for the motorball match or is it only purple armour on her URM body?

If it's the first one, the body for motorball, does she have wheels in her arms?

[image: alita motorball armour]

Maybe it is a design based on the manga and someone knows the answers.

Comment: I just recently watched it and I thought the URM body is so evolved that it can adapt to her needs. When Ido first attaches her head to it, after the body he gave her got destroyed, it changes quite a bit to match her image of herself.

Answer (score 2):

In the manga GUNNM, the narrative arc where she plays motorball is distinct from the one where she gets the Berzerk (or URM) body. For personal reasons explained in the manga, she  put the Berzerk body away and used a motorball dedicated body.

In the movie, it seems implied that with the support of Ido (and perhaps a bit of money) they crafted a Motorball dedicated body, distinct from the Berzerk body. While the Berzerk body is indeed powerful, they may have decided that it would be more efficient to craft a new body (and it would probably be easier to repair).

Take note that in the manga (even more than in the movie), cyborgs seems to change bodies very often (when they are destroyed or just want to adapt to a specific role).

Answer (score 1):

Alita wears *three* separate cyborg bodies in the film, referred to by the makers (in *[Alita: Battle Angel - The Art and Making of the Movie](https://alita-battle-angel.fandom.com/wiki/Alita:_Battle_Angel_-_The_Art_and_Making_of_the_Movie))* as her '*Doll body*', her '*Berserker body*' and her **'*Motorball body*'**.

You can see some concept art (as well as a 3D maquette) of the third body below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The [official novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Alita-Battle-Angel-Official-Novelization/dp/1785658387) doesn't speak to the *underlying* body, but it does note that the pads and armour have been custom-made for her.

> These days, the pads and armour she strapped on were custom-made for
> her by Ido and Gerhad, with a little help from a walking toolbox of a
> man named Ed, who would say, “You’re welcome,” whether you thanked him
> or not. All of it was beautiful and it fitted not only her body but
> her style of movement, with preternaturally responsive nano-sensors
> that reinforced the material at points of impact. Wearing it made her
> feel invincible without slowing her down.

---

You may also be pleased to learn that Alita has an official licenced *Funko Pop*! figurine in her Motorball body.

> **[Alita: Battle Angel - Alita Motorball Body Pop! Vinyl Figure](https://popcultureuk.com/alita-battle-angel-alita-motorball-body-pop-vinyl-figure)**
>
> [image]

Answer (score -2):

> During the course of Battle Angel Alita Alita wore several outfits. In her first cyborg body, this consisted of casual wear in the form of a shirt, track pants, and sneakers. After gaining the Berserker Body, she switched to attire more appropriate for a hunter-warrior that featured black leather in the form of fingerless gloves and a sleeveless shirt and pants. Combined with knee high brown boots and a light yellow trench coat, this is how she appears in the OVA, in which she is transplanted into the Berseker Body soon after being found instead of her first civilian one. In Gunnm: Martian Memory, the trench coat is omitted. Alita's motorball body is depicted as being purple, with the number 99 in yellow on the cover of Killing Angel, the Gunnm 3D special, and Gunnm: Martian Memory.

-this is according to [Alita Wiki](https://battleangel.fandom.com/wiki/Alita)

So to your answer - yes this body, according to the Manga version is different, but in the movie I think it's just enhanced

Comment: OP seems to be referring specifically to the film. Adding in info from the manga isn't a bad thing, but only in the context of answering the main question

Answer (score -2):

It’s the Bezerker body modified. Ido had been working on modifications of rollerball gear that adapted with her body as he stated when he gave her new feet. She didn’t have another body. Adding different arms, hands is the obvious choice to make.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Answer (score -3):

The extras on the Blu-ray confirms that it is a third body.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could [edit] in a transcript, a screenshot, or a timestamp of said extras, to back that up and improve your answer.

Comment: Which extras are you referring to?